# Entity Framework Core Error Transaction 20205

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5

I'm facing an issue with Entity Framework Core 5.0.4 in a .NET5 web project.

I have a `BaseRepository<T>` where I define all the function, for example (full implementation [here](https://github.com/erossini/AdminLTEWithASPNETCore/blob/main/PSC.Repositories/Repositories/BaseRepository.cs))

```
public class BaseRepository<T> : IAsyncRepository<T> where T : class
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The log
    /// </summary>
    protected readonly ILogger _log;

    /// <summary>
    /// The database
    /// </summary>
    protected PSCContext _db;

    public BaseRepository(PSCContext db, ILogger<BaseRepository<T>> log)
    {
        _db = db;
        _log = log;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add a new entity as an asynchronous operation.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="entity">The entity.</param>
    /// <returns>A Task&lt;T&gt; representing the asynchronous operation.</returns>
    public async Task<T> AddAsync(T entity)
    {
        _log.LogDebug($"[{nameof(T)}] Adding a new record");

        await _db.Set<T>().AddAsync(entity);
        await _db.SaveChangesAsync();

        return entity;
    }
}
```

All repositories in my project are based on this base class. I have a lot of insert in my procedure. When I have to save a new record in a repository with `enum` I have this error:

> fail: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Database.Transaction[20205]
> An error occurred using a transaction.

How you see in the following image, I have a lot of insert before this error. In my code there is not transaction at all. The error occurs when I want to save

[image]

The definition of the table is

```
[Table("ImportedHistoryFileLogs")]
public class ImportedHistoryFiletLog : ITable
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedAt { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedAt { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
    public long ImportedHistoryFileId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("ImportedHistoryFileId")]
    public ImportedHistoryFile ImportedHistoryFile { get; set; }
    public DateTime LogData { get; set; } = DateTime.Now;
    public LogType LogType { get; set; } = LogType.Information;
    public LogEventType LogEventType { get; set; } = LogEventType.InternalAction;
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
}
```

This table has a relationship with another table `ImportedHistoryFile`. Before the error, I add in this table the same code for other records.

Not always have this error. Sometimes the procedure stops without any error or message.

Also, I noticed the same error in other tables. Then, I was thinking that Entity Framework Core has a number of operations (like a buffer or concurrency) and when I reach the maximum of the operations it gives me an error. How can I avoid this error?

### Update

Could the issue be related to `SaveChangesAsync()`? Apparently, if I change that line with `_db.SaveChanges();` is working.

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference, but the `AddAsync` is only there for special value generators. For almost all cases `Add` is recommended. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.addasync?view=efcore-5.0

Comment: I've created [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/33319)